# Named Page Sizes

Tags: postscript

I recall at one point reading somewhere that PostScript includes some type of named page sizes, or some sort of preset default media sizes somewhere, but I am unable to find where I might have found this anywhere. (I know one can write `/Letter <</PageSize [612 792]>> def` to name a page media oneself, but that is not what I am looking for.)

Can anyone conform this, or have some idea where this might have been, if it exists?

Also, how can one get locations of the corners of the current page (or the page bounding box), for drawing borders or the like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Language level 1 implementations did have some predefined media sizes, but this is pretty much deprecated with later implementations. However many interpreters still carry definitions around in userdict or statusdict.

From the 3rd Edition PLRM
6.4 Output Device Dictionary
In LanguageLevel 3, certain capabilities of a page device, such as the possible page
sizes or resolutions, can be summarized in an output device dictionary that is
stored as an instance of the OutputDevice resource category. This enables applications
to query device capabilities directly and also maintains functional equivalence
with LanguageLevel 1 (where information on page size capabilities is
indicated by the presence of userdict entries such as letter, legal, and a4).

From the second edition PLRM
userdict operators There are operators defined in the userdict dictionary that cause an
imageable region to be defined. Examples of these operators include,
but are not limited to: a4, a4small, b5, ledger, legal, letter, lettersmall,
and note. These operators perform the equivalent of an initgraphics
and an erasepage. These operators must not be used in an EPS file, as
they will erase the entire page that includes the EPS file.

Sadly I no longer have a copy of the first edition PLRM.

The canonical method for finding the page bounding box is something like

```
initgraphics     %% reset graphics state to the initial state
clippath         %% set the currant path to be the current clip path (ie the page)
flattenpath      %% shouldn't be required, as the initial clip should be rectangular...
pathbbox         %% get the path bounding box
```

Comment: PLRM 1ed doesn't mention these. But I think they (some, maybe) were present in Adobe interpreters from the LaserWriter on. In a level-1 printer, I think you'd setup the name to also select the input media and output tray.